# Isomorphism between Cartesian product of a vector space and the space of linear maps

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, vector-space-isomorphism

Let $V$ be a vector space defined over the field $\mathbb{F}$. Given a positive integer $n$, prove that $V^n = V \times V \cdots \times V$ ($n$ times) is isomorphic to $\mathcal{L}(\mathbb{F}^n, V)$ where $\mathcal{L}(\mathbb{F}^n, V)$ is the vector space of linear maps from $\mathbb{F}^n$ to $V$.

I am not sure how to approach this, especially since $V$ is not even assumed to be finite dimensional. What is the isomorphism between the two vector spaces?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An element $f\in\mathcal{L}(\mathbb{F}^n,V)$ is totally determined by its values on the canonical basis $(e_i)_{i=1,\dots,n}$ of $\mathbb{F}^n$.
$$v_i = f(e_i)\in V.$$
You can check that
$$f\longmapsto(f(e_1),\cdots,f(e_n))$$
is an isomorphism.